# Zend2 : how default skeleton 'Application module' is rendered, when i trigger Album module?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Iam just starting with Zend2. i went through this [Zend doc](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/skeleton-application.html) and it is very useful in setting up the project/ understand the flow. i setup my first module Album (mentioned in the tutor) and it is working fine.
**What i wanted to understand is,**
i trigger the album module using link
http://localhost/album and i get the browser output in such a way that Album module output is embedded into another default module 'Application'. 
The
when i trigger the localhost url http://localhost/album,  i expect the output of only the Album module which is written in viewscripts and it's output is basic html output with table. Could you please let me know how the application module gets executed when i trigger album module?

i am aware that we configure userdefined modules in **zf\config\application.config.php** file

i know myquery here is a basic thing which i didnt understand. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When your ZF2 application is booted all modules in your application.config.php are loaded. It is a misconception to think that if you use a route from a certain module that all other modules are ignored. This is also explained [here](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started-with-zend-studio/skeleton-application.html#starting-up) and [this flow chart](http://okeowoaderemi.com/site/assets/files/1103/zf2-flowchart.jpg) can also be helpful to understand the ZF2 processes.

Comment: its ok that all other modules are executing. How the data of Album module is getting loaded into Application module. i didnt mention anything explicitly to do this integration between Album and Application modules

Comment: @Lyon You probably used a view from the view template map from your application module.